Specify erronous foreign key in SQLite EF Core when receiving 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'
I am using a SQLite database for unit testing purposes. The only issue I have is that when foreign key constraints are violated the error message does not specify the specific violation but instead a more generic

SQLite Error 19: 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed'

I have tried to add .EnableDetailedErrors() when building the dbcontext without any luck.
Just to clarify I am using the using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite package in a .NET 7 environment with EF Core 7.

Is there any way to get a more clear foreign key error from the SQLite connector?


Don't think so. This message come from SQLite engine. Try to log SQL and check on which SQL DML statement it fails.
